# SSIS with c# script Task referencing a custom dll where namespace has a dot in it

Tags: c#, ssis

I have an SSIS with a script task (C#). This package works when running locally (Visual Studio 2015) but does not when running as sql job (SSISDB integration services catalog). The error is "Script Task:Error:CS0246 - The type or namespace name 'work' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), ScriptMain.cs, 217, 35"

ScriptMain.cs line 217 is
var process = new work.Provision.Provisioner(bla bla);

The assembly reference is there as a dll (the filename is work.Provision.dll). The good guy who built this dll left the company. The namespace is "work.Provision". Could it be that the SSIS is confused and expecting a namespace called "work"?

How do I solve this?
We do have the source code and probably needs to rework it so the namespace is "workProvision" (remove the dot) to avoid confusion - maybe, I don't know I'm not an expert. Keep in mind this whole thing works when I run it locally on Visual Studio (2015).

Many thanks!

Comment: Is this running on the same server where it's always run or has the package moved to a new server?

Comment: HI, the package is new on a non production environment (not yet deployed to production)

Comment: My guess is that you need to install the custom assembly onto the new server's global assembly cache (GAC). Command line is approximately `gactutil.exe -if work.provision.dll` but first you have to find out where/whether gacutil is installed

Comment: I fixed this by building the DLL with correct .Net framework and changed project target sql server to correct version; Also inside the script task I used "assembly resolve" found in this article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/dec/12/loading-net-assemblies-out-of-seperate-folders